# android app can not load a json file from a pc in same network

Tags: android

I found a code for loading a JSON file from a server for android app.Then i wanted to change url of server to my PC(http://192.168.68.104/json/movies.json). I set up an IIS and a server on my pc. Then both pc and my mobile connect to a wireless. I can brows json file in my pc and mobile browser. But my app on mobile can not load that json file. why?

```
package info.androidhive.customlistviewvolley;

import info.androidhive.customlistviewvolley.adater.CustomListAdapter;
import info.androidhive.customlistviewvolley.app.AppController;
import info.androidhive.customlistviewvolley.model.Movie;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.VolleyLog;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonArrayRequest;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    // Log tag
private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

// Movies json url
private static final String url = "http://192.168.68.104/json/movies.json";
private ProgressDialog pDialog;
private List<Movie> movieList = new ArrayList<Movie>();
private ListView listView;
private CustomListAdapter adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    adapter = new CustomListAdapter(this, movieList);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    // Showing progress dialog before making http request
    pDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
    pDialog.show();

    // changing action bar color
    getActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(
            new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#1b1b1b")));

    // Creating volley request obj
    JsonArrayRequest movieReq = new JsonArrayRequest(url,
            new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {

                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, response.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
                    hidePDialog();

                    // Parsing json
                    for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                        try {

                            JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject(i);
                            Movie movie = new Movie();
                            movie.setTitle(obj.getString("title"));
                            movie.setThumbnailUrl(obj.getString("image"));
                            movie.setRating(((Number) obj.get("rating"))
                                    .doubleValue());
                            movie.setYear(obj.getInt("releaseYear"));

                            // Genre is json array
                            JSONArray genreArry = obj.getJSONArray("genre");
                            ArrayList<String> genre = new ArrayList<String>();
                            for (int j = 0; j < genreArry.length(); j++) {
                                genre.add((String) genreArry.get(j));
                            }
                            movie.setGenre(genre);

                            // adding movie to movies array
                            movieList.add(movie);

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }

                    // notifying list adapter about data changes
                    // so that it renders the list view with updated data
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                    hidePDialog();

                }
            });

    // Adding request to request queue
    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(movieReq);
    //Toast.makeText(this,movieList.size(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    hidePDialog();
}

private void hidePDialog() {
    if (pDialog != null) {
        pDialog.dismiss();
        pDialog = null;
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="info.androidhive.customlistviewvolley"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="11"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />


<application
    android:name="info.androidhive.customlistviewvolley.app.AppController"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="info.androidhive.customlistviewvolley.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: How are we supposed to even remotely guess without seeing code?

Comment: code is not important, because it operates correctly with orginal server addrese

Comment: You're complaining that you can't see it in your app.  We don't know what your app is doing.  So yes, code is important-  otherwise we can't tell you what you're doing wrong.

Comment: This might be a typo in your post, but in your post you say your ip is 192.168.68.105, your code uses 192.168.68.104

Comment: at now, i cheked it again. it work with original url(http://api.androidhive.info/json/movies.json) correctly. but with my local url it dont work

Comment: My log in eclipce showed onErrorResponse.

Comment: Probably has to do with firewalls or networking. The security rules change between accessing an external resource and internal one. Can you access that URL from another PC on the same wireless network?

Comment: in then same network even i can see that json file with chrome in mobile. but my app can not load that and raise OnErrorResponse.

Comment: Guys, my pc and my mobile connect to a router and my router is connecting to ISP. is it any problem with my ISP?

Comment: Provide `Port Number` as well when accessing your PC with URL `"http://192.168.68.104/json/movies.json"` I will suggest you to check your connection by starting your server (xampp wampp etc) and check the root url if it is working or not i-e: `http://192.168.68.104:8080` (it may not be 8080 but take it as example)